# Anko doAsync how to wait for activity to be recreated before uiThread

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I am using Anko with Kotlin to perform a long running background task (about 3-5 seconds) in my application.

After the task is finished I notify the user that it is indeed finished and move to another activity

The code I use is this:

```
fun send_data() {
     doAsync {
        try {
            //long running task
            uiThread {
                val intent = Intent(this.weakRef.get(), ResultActivity::class.java)                    startActivity(intent)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, e.localizedMessage, e);
            uiThread {
                snackbar(base_view, "Error while initializing:${e.localizedMessage}", "Retry", { _ -> send_data() })
            }
        }
}
```

during this the user could do a lot of actions that would cause my activity to be recreated , now I can check that the activity is active by using the `this.weakRef` to see if it is null, but if it is indeed null, is there a way to wait for the activity to be recreated before continueing?

right now what I do is check if the weakRef is null or not and if it is I post a new `handler` to run again in 200 ms and every 200ms until `weakRef` is no longer null

is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't think that just using anko will do the trick for you. Your question is more about app architecture. To start with, I would look at [MVP](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvp-architecture) or even [this](https://proandroiddev.com/a-guided-tour-inside-a-clean-architecture-code-base-48bb5cc9fc97) to familiarise yourself with concepts of how app can survive those configuration changes

Comment: This is very interesting and I am using a similar approach, fragments are the only ones that have views and communicate with the activity through interfaces, the activity takes those commands and propagates them to a fragment with `retainInstanceState` which is basically the equivalent to the `Presenter` mentioned in the links, the problem is what happens when the `Presenter` has some work to do on the main thread and the activity that it is attached to is in the middle of being recreated

Comment: The way we do it, is we have a `Fragment ` and a class, which instantiates from Android's `ViewModel`, which is injected into the fragment `onActivityCreated()` method. A fragment requests `ViewModel` to do some work via function. The `ViewModel` does some work and pushes it's result onto `Relay` (https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay), to which a fragment subscribes inside `onCreateView` method. Thus, even if the fragment has been recreated, it will receive last pushed onto relay value (`BehaviourRelay` retains latest received value)

Comment: Also, if you are familiar with Dagger (https://google.github.io/dagger/), take a look at this concept https://medium.com/@iammert/new-android-injector-with-dagger-2-part-1-8baa60152abe

Comment: No my problem is not returning the result to the correct `Activity`, I use fragment's `onAttach` and `onDetach` to keep a reference to the current activity that is using it. My problem is what happens between `onDetach` but before a new `Activity` is created and reattaches the `Fragment`, I have not used dagger, but I will give it a look

Answer (score 0):

Weak reference is not intended for such usage. You should consider using listener or observable pattern.

```
val listener : ListenerObject? = CustomListenerObject()
fun send_data() {
     doAsync {
        try {
            //long running task
            uiThread {
                listener?.onSuccess()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, e.localizedMessage, e)
            uiThread {
                listener?.onFailure()
            }
        }
}

fun onDestroy() {
    listener = null
}
```

Edit:
As anko will not trigger uiThread if activity is finishing you can implement some kind of cache that will be reused if `send_data()` is triggered second time.

Comment: well if the activity is finishing I don't mind if the user does not get the results, that probably means that they navigated away from it, my problem is what happens when the ui is required but the activity is in the middle of being recreated

Comment: @Cruces It's complex issue - you can build listener outside activity lifecycle and recreated activity can check if there is data or request waiting. Usually it could be implemented with 'headless fragment' <-- fragment without UI or newest approach: LiveData + architecture components ViewModel.